# Hardware assisted virtualization on acer aspire 5935g

Tags: cpu, hardware-virtualization

I would like to make hardware assisted virtualization work on my acer aspire 5935g. But my current configuration has Intel core 2 duo p7450  which **doesnt** support intel VT technology.

I'm wondering if i buy new penryn CPU with VT support if it will work with my system, and can i use VT with it? ?

My BIOS doesnt show any options for (en/dis)abling VT. Would this mean i will have to update the bios as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are it probably won't work - laptops arn't generally designed to be upgradable in that fashion, there's unlikely to be a bios for that specific model that supports VT or a processor other than the one it comes with.

Comment: Right know i found this page [link](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Acer-Aspire-5935G-Series.27194.0.html) which show that my nb was also manufactured with Intel Core 2 Duo T9550. And this cpu supports VT and than must exists BIos for that feature. So maybe it can be done. Or am i wrong ?

Comment: Same model, different sub-model/motherboard. the Bios might not be cross compatible. *If* they have the same motherboard submodel, or you're willing to take the risk of buying a processor on blind faith, and risking bricking your notebook, go ahead.

Comment: OK so thx i appreciate your advice.Its too risky so I let it be.

Comment: Unanswered questions tend to get bounced up periodically, so i'd appreciate it if you'd select this answer as the correct one. If there's a better answer, you can always switch in future.